# Какую лицензию использовать для своей cms

Tags: github

Я создал cms, которую продолжаю развивать и дальше.
Вот решил выложить на GitHub, но вопрос в следующем.

Какую выбрать лицензию из списка GitHub при публикации репозитория?

Cms будет бесплатной, не для коммерческого использования.

Comment: Что вы хотите предотвратить? // начнём с этого

Comment: Я уже прочёл в сети. По идее мне нужна лицензия MIT. Что бы при копировании, пользователи могли распространять продукт только с сохранением моих авторских прав. Но я не знаю подходит ли она для моих целей, что бы никто не смог использовать систему в коммерческих целях.

Comment: Вы повторили вопрос, но не привели пример.

Comment: Хочу предотвратить копирование системы с изменением авторских прав. То есть копирование может быть, но с сохранением моих авторских прав.

Comment: так вроде все кроме может быть public domain сохраняют авторские

Comment: Можно немножко подробнее, не очень Вас понял?

Comment: Защита от перепродажи и упущения тем самым... Чего? Чужих средств потраченных на бесплатный код? Полезных изменений в проект? Или чего? Ваша CMS и так ваша, пока вы способны это доказать.

Comment: Были моменты, когда мою разработку уже продавали под чужими копирайтами, хотя она бесплатна. Вот и решаю теперь головоломку.

Comment: @Владимир они, скорее всего, не имели на это права ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯